# default sort by desc

Tags: magento-1.9, sort

I am trying to update the default sort options for list pages. Here's what I have in catalog.xml

```
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setAvailableOrders" json="value">
            <value><![CDATA[{"news_from_date":"New Arrivals","price":"Price"}]]></value>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>news_from_date</string></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

When I load a category page, the products are sorted ascending but the toolbar is indicating that they're sorted descending.
If I click on the ascending icon, it will reload the grid in ascending order.
If I then click on the descending icon, the grid will reload with the items in descending order.

Comment: Did you changed ***catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml***? If so, try to copy it from rwd theme: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml into your theme, and check if it works. If it works - then your toolbar.phtml is not good, you've broke backward compatibility with modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem yireo has a GTM module, https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager that is setting the sort order to ASC on line 154 https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager/blob/master/source/app/code/community/Yireo/GoogleTagManager/Block/Category.php am not sure why they do this but i reported the bug to them